# Maven assembly plugin fails to execute

Tags: maven

I'm getting this message after attempting to "mvn package". It seems like there's an issue with retrieving the google collections jar, but I'm not sure if that's the only problem.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.3:single (make-assembly) on project recommender:
  Execution make-assembly of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.3:single failed:
  Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.3 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved:
  Failed to collect dependencies for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:jar:2.3 ():
  Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.google.collections:google-collections:jar:1.0:
  Could not transfer artifact com.google.collections:google-collections:pom:1.0 from/to central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): 
  Specified destination directory cannot be created: /Users/danquach/.m2/repository/com/google/collections/google-collections/1.0 -> [Help 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

The original error should be a local problem:

```
Specified destination directory cannot be created:
/Users/danquach/.m2/repository/com/google/collections/google-collections/1.0
```

- Is your drive full?
- Do you have write access to this path?

You can try to create `/Users/danquach/.m2/repository/com/google/collections` and call maven again.

Comment: ah, looks like prepending "sudo" to "mvn package" allowed me to create the directory.

Comment: This should work without superuser rights ... The rights for `.m2` and all subdirectories of `repository` should be `drwxr-xr-x`. Try `chmod u+rwx,g+rx,o+rx /Users/danquach/.m2 -R`

Comment: The directory rights are just as you described..in any case, I am not invoking superuser with subsequent "mvn package" calls, it seems to work as expected again.